# print sep='' not working in Python 2.7.8

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

As a trial, I used the following code in Python 2.7.8:

```
print 'one', 'two', 'three', sep =''
```

The message, I got, was

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The output I wanted, was

> onetwothree

Comment: Was editing question necessary? If it helped someone in anyway, that's fine.

Comment: It was necessary because you didnt format your code which makes it hard to read

Answer (score 4):

`print()` function is a Python 3 feature but you can get it on Python 2 like so

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print('one', 'two', 'three', sep='')
onetwothree
```